# Manejar el cierre de una App en Android

Tags: java, android

Quisiera que al momento de cerrar mi aplicación en segundo plano, por ejemplo al realizar el swipe como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y posteriormente que al volver a entrar a la aplicación, esta siga con la sesión de usuario activa y que me deje en el `Activity` que quedé la ultima vez antes de cerrarla.

Actualmente al cerrarla y volver a entrar me deja en el Activity inicial y debo volver a iniciar sesión.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estas realizando es eliminando completamente la ejecución de la aplicación en la memoria, por lo tanto al iniciar abrira con su estado inicial.
 Si deseas que guarde el estado, deberás guardar algunos valores mediante algún [método de almacenamiento](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html?hl=es) (base de datos, preferecias, archivos), pero debes considerar que si desea guardar una sesión dependiendo de que tan sensible es la información de tus credenciales podrías considerar incluso guardar la sesión mediante un webservice.

Esto es un ejemplo sencillo donde mediante el valor de una preferencia determina que abrir al inicio de la aplicación, la pantalla para autenticarse o la pantalla principal de la aplicación cuando se tienen credenciales:

```
//Obtiene valor de sesion activa.
boolean sesionActiva = obtieneValorSesion(getApplicationContext());

//Valida si muestra pantalla de Login o MainActivity desde una Splash Activity.
if(sesionActiva){ 
  //Abre pantalla principal.
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);      
}else{
  //Abre pantalla para autenticarse.
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Los métodos requeridos para guardar el valor de la sesión serían:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void guardaValorSesion(Context context, Boolean valorsesion) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sesion", valorsesion);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean obtieneValorSesion(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getBoolean("sesion", false); //valor default false
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Un placer, espero hayas solucionado tu requerimiento!  Saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres persistir los estados de tus actividades, puedes revisar el ciclo de vida de [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

- Implementa la persistencia del estado de tu actividad en `onStop()` o `onPause()`.
- Implementa reconstrucción del estado en `onStart()` o `onPause()`.

Así quedas con una aplicación que mantiene sus datos independiente si esta interumpido por otra actividad, cerrado por el usuario o eliminado por uso de memoria.